# Django Raw SQL relation does not exists

Tags: django, postgresql, django-settings, django-database

I am trying to execute raw sql but it requires a relation and I am not really sure where and why it doesnt work as it should.

Settings.py

```
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'Primary', 
        'USER': 'user', 
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'host', 
        'PORT': '5433',
    },
    'DataDB': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'SpecialDataDB', 
        'USER': 'user', 
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'host', 
        'PORT': '5433',
    }
}
```

getData.py

```
    
    if request.GET['data'] == True:
        with connections['DataDB'].cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("Select i from Test")
            row = cursor.fetchone()
            return cursor
    return None
```

I have no problem connecting to first database and use my user to authenticate, then I am trying to grab data from 2nd database (that should be read only) and I get error:

`relation "test" does not exist LINE 1: Select i from Test`

2nd Database is only for read, why not DBRouter? I've created it before and it didnt work as intended.

All I want to do now is get that raw data and return it to the view.

On the other hand I can create table using raw query.

`cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (i integer)")`

^ that works

How should I write select query to get the data without creating a model or how to create the model that's gonna work with it?

Comment: Names are case sensitive and you have both `Test` and `test` - is that your issue?

Comment: Tested that, it is not the issue, even if I use connections['default'].cursor() I get the error.
I created a model named Test to see whats wrong. I deleted the database table. Made migrations. It created table Test in default. Tried to read from both default and DataDB but nothing happens.